# Call a method after subscription Angular

Tags: angular, onresize

i want to call a method after a window resize, but with 500 ms delay. I did it like this and it is working, but would you do it in the same way? Im new in Angular

```
resizeEvent$: Subject<MouseEvent> = new Subject<MouseEvent>();

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.resizeEvent$.next(event);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.resizeEvent$.debounceTime(300).subscribe( data => this.initJourney());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention the version of your Angular and RxJS but I assume you are using RxJS v6+.

So you need to use `pipe` method to use `debounceTime`
First import `debounceTime`:

```
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.resizeEvent$
     .pipe(
       debounceTime(300)
     )
    .subscribe( data => this.initJourney());
}
```

**Update**

I think you need to change `Subject<MouseEvent>` to `Subject<Event>`.

**Update 2**

There is another way which does not involve `debounceTime`. You can use `setTimeout` in event listener method as follows. Make sure to remove the subject and the subscription in `ngOnInit`.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.initJourney();
    },300);
}
```

Comment: if he's using angular 6 it doesn't mean that he uses RxJS 6

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu Yeah, you are right. Editing the post.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thx for your fast reply (im using angular 7).
But isnt there another way:

```
.subscribe( data => this.initJourney());
```

looks weird, data is unused

Comment: You can use comments to ask further questions like this. This area is for answers only. I edited the question. Please see "Update 2" section.